# Permissions in folder owned by group www-data

Tags: permissions, www-data

I run apache2 webserver on Debian 9 and root of that web is located in */srv/www/*, I am logged as user *tomsk*, problem is that I don't have a permissions in */srv/www/* because it is owned by *www-data* group.

As far as I know, *www-data* has only read permissions in that folder so I shouldn't give a write permission for group *www-data* in that folder.

Let's say that I have a group named *developers* and I am a member of that group. What I have to do to give a permissions for group *developers* in folder */srv/www/*, without affecting a apache2's default *www-data* group?

**EDIT:** Shouln't it be **2470**? Because user (www-data) can only read, group (developers) can do anything and others cannot do anything.

Comment: Adding developers to www-data won’t do what you want?

Comment: No, because it is insecure.

Comment: And letting developers access production servers and develop right on the server is secure? Or you want to secure a development environment?

Comment: No that developers group is just example.. that /srv/www folder should be unlocked only for certain group.. for example someone gets into server, so he cannot without sudo do anything to /srv/www (because he wont be in that group)